# What is the Ukrainian translation for English phrase "You're right"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Is there a phrase in Ukrainian that has a similar meaning?

[Google Translate gives](https://translate.google.com/#en/uk/You%27re%20right) me following: *Ти маєш рацію* and *Ти правий*

Is there any difference between them? Which one is preferable? Any alternatives?

Comment: Ohh, that's interesting question. The fact is that O. Ponomariv [claims that it's Russianism and wrong](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/frazeologiya#toc13) to say "ти правий" in meaning "you are correct". Still, O. Ponomariv seems to be wrong here; it can be easily proven by finding usages of "правий" in classical Ukrainian literature; despite all my respect to Ponomariv, sometimes he acts as hyper-purist. So, IMHO, the practical difference appears that "ти правий"∈{"you're right [correct]", "you're right [not left]"}, "ти маєш рацію"∈{"you're correct", "you have a radio set"}.

Comment: Although that opinion of O. Ponomariv is worth a separate Ukrainian discussion. Maybe I'm wrong in my claims that he acts as hyper-purist here.

Answer (score 4):

*Ти правий* literally means "you are *правий*". *[Правий](http://sum.in.ua/s/pravyj)*, according to the academic explanatory “Dictionary of the Ukrainian language” in 11 volumes (a.k.a. СУМ-11), has the following meanings:

- "Right" as direction (opposite to "left").
- "Right" as in "[right-wing politics](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-wing_politics)".
- "Clockwise" (only in very specific contexts, per my opinion).
- "Not guilty" (usually about humans).
- "Just, fair, equitable" (both about humans and about their thoughts/actions/etc).
- "Right, correct, rational" (both about humans and about their thoughts/actions/etc). [Some linguists claim that this meaning is non-native for Ukrainians, but was borrowed from the Russian language; never-the-less it's widely used today.](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/928/4)
- "Straight, not curved/crooked" (rare).

So, ignoring all rare and non-applicable meanings, *ти правий* means "you are right/correct", "you are just/fair-minded/even-handed" or "you have no guilt". While *some* linguists say that the last two meanings are preferred, still it's *widely* used as "you are right/correct".

---

*Ти маєш рацію* literally means "you have *рація*". *[Рація](http://sum.in.ua/s/racija)*, according to the same dictionary, has the following meanings:

- "Rationale, reasoning, calculation". Especially in phrases like *мати рацію* (literally "to have *рація*", effectively "to be correct/rational, to say/do reasoned things"), *визнавати чиюсь рацію* ("to accept somebody's rationale"), etc.
- "A hand-held transceiver, walkie-talkie". A Soviet-time contraction of *радіостанція* ("a radio set"). Probably, is less used within the phrases that are commonly used for previous meaning — and actually Ukrainians seem to tend to say more often *в X є Y* ("in X's ownership, there is Y") about corporeal things rather than literally "X has Y" (*X має Y*) — but still theoretically can be used in phrases typical for previous meaning (like *мати рацію*) too (especially by speakers with Russian background, not aware of previous meaning and thus not feeling the problem).
- (Very obsolete) "salutatory, felicitation, congratulations".

Therefore, ignoring obsolete meanings, *ти маєш рацію* can mean "you're right [your thoughts/actions are correct/rational]" or "you have a hand-held transceiver (walkie-talkie)".

---

Another variants are:

- *Твоя правда* (literally: "your truth").
- *Твоя думка слушна* ("your opinion is relevant/correct"), *твої слова слушні* ("your words are relevant/correct"), *ти кажеш слушно* ("you say relevant things / correctly").