# Чи справді вираз «ти правий» у значеннях «твоя правда», «ти маєш рацію» є росіянізмом?

Tags: росіянізм, словосполучення

Олександр Пономарів у книзі «Культура слова: мовностилістичні поради» (2008) стверджує:

> #### [Мати рацію, а не бути правим](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/frazeologiya#toc13)
>
> <…пропущено два абзаци на захист виразів «мати рацію» та «твоя/ваша правда», що жодних заперечень у мене не викликають…>
>
> Натомість прихильники зближення мов обстоювали та обстоюють калькований російський вислів *ви праві*, хоч основними значеннями слова *пра́вий* у нашій мові є «справедливий, праведний, безгрішний, невинний», а не «слушний». Ще менше пасують до згаданого фразеологізму омонім *пра́вий* (протилежне поняття до лівий) та омограф *прави́й* «рівний, прямий»: «Рубайся, дерево, криве і праве» (Номис).
>
> Отже, повноцінними українськими відповідниками російського вислову *Вы (ты) правы (прав)* є *Ви (ти) маєте (маєш) рацію*; *Ваша (твоя) правда*. Варіантові *Ви (ти) праві (правий)* віддають перевагу ті, які *дякують Вас* (замість *вам*), *заключають* (замість *укладають*) угоди, голосують за *змішану* (замість *мішану*) виборчу систему, вимовляють свої прізвища *Алексєєнко*, *Кра́вець*, *Логвін*, *Пєхота*, *Кутовой* (замість нормальних *Олексієнко*, *Краве́ць*, *Логвин*, *Піхота*, *Кутовий*).

Наскільки це правда? Чи справді вираз «ти правий» (у значеннях: «твоя правда», «ти маєш рацію») є росіянізмом і нерекомендованим до вжитку?

Answer (score 16):

Maksymus у блозі ua-etymology [показує численні приклади використання «ти правий» в українській літературі](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/273905.html):

- Франко: Ви праві, що поки що серйозної праці й системи в нім не видко.
- Драгоманов: І хоч, певно, Ви праві психологично, а я правий і юридично, — бо міг би Вам доказати детально…
- Винниченко: От я й хочу вам сказать, що ви праві.

(Я наводжу три, але їх там більше — не кажучи про ті, що можна власноруч познаходити на Google Books: [1](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%22),  [2](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%22), [3](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B21%22).)

Дехто може заперечити, мовляв, застосовувати «ти правий» / «Ви праві» можна, але лише коли ми кажемо про справедливість (тобто правильність думок і вчинків людини в цілому, особливо щодо інших людей), а не про слушність (тобто раціонільність її думки чи вчинка в конкретному випадку). Але межа видається мені доволі хиткою, бо навіть саме слово «справедливий» можна застосовувати щодо слушності в конкретній ситуації, кажучи «твоя думка справедлива»:

- Якою міцею теоретичної думки <…> треба було владати, щоб <…> відзначити справедливу думку від непевних практичних заходів <…>. //Михайло Павлюк «Михайло Петрович Драгоманов, 1841–1895: його юбілей, смерть, автобіографія і спис творів» (1896).
- Думка ся не зовсїм справедлива. //Іван Линниченко «Суспільні верстви Галицької Руси XIV-XV в.» (1899).
- Ся думка була зовсїм справедлива. //З перекладу роману «Жерміналь» Е. Золя в українському журналі (1904).

Єдине, що мене непокоїть із даним виразом — це те, що кажучи «ти правий» у значенні «ти маєш рацію», я майже завжди підсвідомо ставлю наголос на останній склад. А «пра́вий» у мене дійсно асоціюється лише зі справедливим у глобальному сенсі (а не слушним у конкретній ситуації). Тим не менше наголоси то є доволі нечітка річ: он [Ніковський (1927)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=8) та [Андрусишин і Крет (1955)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=8) кажуть, що пра́вий — справедливий, а прави́й — протилежний до лівого або прямий, у той час як той же О. Пономарів, можливо, слідуючи [Грінченку (1909)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=12), [Кримському та Єфремову (1933)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=1) чи [СУМ-11 (1976)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pravyj), стверджує, що пра́вий — справедливий або протилежний до лівого, а прави́й — прямий, при цьому [Уманець і Спілка (1896)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=9) в усіх випадках «а» наголошують.